# Drag-and-Dropping a column in a grid — but nothing happens in my JUnit test

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I would like to test Selenium Drag-and-Drop a column in a grid.

I use the method `dragAndDrop(String locator, String movementsString)` but nothing happens when I run the test with JUnit.

Below is the code:

```
browser.dragAndDrop ("//col[@id='" + TreeGridHelper.getTreeGridTagId() + 
                        "_head_before_"+ numCol + "']", "850,0");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to switch to **WebDriver** to get better support and an improving framework..

To drag and drop WebElements with WebDriver you can use [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks) Tutorial which isn't perfect but quite useful